# Multiple TabWidget?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

how to create multiple tabwidget in a tabhost, i get nullpointer exception when i do that

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that second TabWidget in there.

If you're asking about adding more than 1 tab to a TabHost see this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Check Step 6 carefully where a newTabSpec() is created.

Comment: I tried to add multiple TabSpec , but i got an error , can you please give me a simple exmaple

Comment: The link I have posted is a simple example.

Comment: i have seen the example and it is helpful , but it creates only one tabhost, i want to have two tabhost one in the top and one in the buttom which manipulates the same FrameLayout

Answer (score 1):

To add multiple tabs you have to create tabSpec objects than add each tabspec using .addTab() method of TabbHost.

> Example

```
myTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
myTabHost.setup(this,getsupportFragmentManager(),android.R.id.tabcontent);
myTabHost.addTab(myTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1",null), SomeFragmentClass.class,null);

myTabHost.addTab(myTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2",null), AnotherFragmentClass.class,null); // just pass fragment classes with it
```

I hop it will help...